# How can I properly break a big controller action to smaller pieces in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently working with a team that use mongoDb for the project, it has one super big entity called `Project`, this project entity contain other classes, and all of this should be inserted in one action as one project, for example:

```
public class Project
{
    public GeneralInfo BuildinGeneralInfo { get; set; }

    public List<ResidentalGeneralInfo> ResidentalGeneralInfo { get; set;     }

    public List<CommercialOffice> OfficeGeneralInfo { get; set; }

    public List<CommercialOffice> BusinessGeneralInfo { get; set; }
//etc...
}
```

and in `GeneralInfo` for example we have:

```
public class GeneralInfo
{

    public string Elevation { get; set; }

    public string ElevationEn { get; set; }

    public string Floors { get; set; }

    public DateTime BuildDate { get; set; }

    public string LandArea { get; set; } 
//etc...
}
```

what I did was create a method as follow:

```
private GeneralInfo InsertGeneralInfo(string Elevation, string ElevationEn, string Floors, DateTime BuildDate, string LandArea, string ResidentalUnit, string BusinessUnit, string OfficeUnit, string ArchitectureStyle, string ArchitectureStyleEn, string StructureType, string StructureTypeEn, string ResidentalUnitInFloor, string BusinessUnitInFloor, string OfficeUnitInFloor, string Yard, string ParkingCapasity, string HeatCool, string HeatCoolEn, string Foundation)
    {
        var generalInfoObj = new GeneralInfo
        {
            Elevation = Elevation,
            ElevationEn = ElevationEn,
            Floors = Floors,
            BuildDate = BuildDate,
            LandArea = LandArea,
            ResidentalUnit = ResidentalUnit,
            BusinessUnit = BusinessUnit,
            OfficeUnit = OfficeUnit,
            ArchitectureStyle = ArchitectureStyle,
            ArchitectureStyleEn = ArchitectureStyleEn,
            StructureType = StructureType,
            StructureTypeEn = StructureTypeEn,
            ResidentalUnitInFloor = ResidentalUnitInFloor,
            BusinessUnitInFloor = BusinessUnitInFloor,
            OfficeUnitInFloor = OfficeUnitInFloor,
            Yard = Yard,
            ParkingCapasity = ParkingCapasity,
            HeatCool = HeatCool,
            HeatCoolEn = HeatCoolEn,
            Foundation = Foundation
        };

        return generalInfoObj;
    }
```

and then used it in my action like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(GeneralInfo generalInfoModel)
    {
        var project = new Project();


        project.BuildinGeneralInfo = InsertGeneralInfo(generalInfoModel.Elevation, generalInfoModel.ElevationEn,
            generalInfoModel.Floors, generalInfoModel.BuildDate, generalInfoModel.LandArea,
            generalInfoModel.ResidentalUnit, generalInfoModel.BusinessUnit, generalInfoModel.OfficeUnit,
            generalInfoModel.ArchitectureStyle, generalInfoModel.ArchitectureStyleEn, generalInfoModel.StructureType,
            generalInfoModel.StructureTypeEn, generalInfoModel.ResidentalUnitInFloor, generalInfoModel.BusinessUnitInFloor,
            generalInfoModel.OfficeUnitInFloor, generalInfoModel.Yard, generalInfoModel.ParkingCapasity,
            generalInfoModel.HeatCool, generalInfoModel.HeatCoolEn, generalInfoModel.Foundation);

        return View();
    }
```

but I feel this might be a naive implementation and there might be far better approach then this for breaking a big controller action, I'd appreciate any help in this regard, and on top of that I think my team shouldn't be using this big entity like that, but I have no control over that, I'd also appreciate any comment as to whether using entity like this is a code smell and bad architecture design.

Comment: Why are you doing all this? You have an instance of `GeneralInfo` (the parameter `generalInfoModel`). All you need is `project.BuildinGeneralInfo = generalInfoModel'`. All your current code is doing is creating a duplicate of what you already have.

Comment: You're right, what a stupid mistake, I've got a little disappointed in myself actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you get object of type GeneralInfo as input parameter and then use another method that creates new object of the same type which is exactly the same as input one, and then you assign it to Project object. It would be the same as if you would just assign the input object to Project object property.

```
project.BuildinGeneralInfo = generalInfoModel;
```

Maybe I missed something, but it looks like you over complicated everything.